# Qt Chart Series remove not shown data crashes

Tags: c++, qt, graph, charts, qtcharts

I'm trying to make a live plotting graph class in qt and the scrolling works.
But when watching my program in Task Manager I recognized that the CPU and RAM usage increases by time (and data).

So I thought it would be a good style to use the [remove](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html#remove-2) function to delete data which is not shown anyway.
Here's my code:

```
void Live_Chart::UpdateY(float yValue)
{
xValue++;
this->yValue = yValue;
m_series->append(xValue, yValue);

if (xValue > m_axisX->max())
{
    // "Scroll" the data in the view
    m_axisX->setMax(xValue);
    m_axisX->setMin(m_axisX->min()+1);

    // Remove the previous data we don't see
    qDebug() << "Removing " << m_axisX->min();
    m_series->remove(m_axisX->min());
}
}
```

This method is called every 100 ms with a random number in between 0 and 10.

But always when reaching removing=52 the program crashes with this error msg:

```
ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::remove: "index out of range", file c:\users\qt\work\qt\qtbase\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h, line 483
```

And I really have no clue why 52. This number isn't specified in any part of my program. The range of the x-axis is 50. On the create of the QLineSeries I am adding the point (0, 0).

EDIT:
When using a m_axisX range of (0, 20) the program crashes when trying to delete point 22.

--> The program crashes when deleting a point whith x = x-range + 2 (Tested with other numbers too).

Comment: can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: I don't know how a reprex could be different than my program, maybe my edit helps?

Comment: `QVector::remove` takes the index of the to be removed element. It is unclear how `m_series->remove(m_axisX->min());` and then later incrementing `min` and calling `m_series->remove(m_axisX->min());` again, is supposed to work correctly. Suppose old min is 42, you remove element at index 42 then why on the next call do you want to remove the element at index 43 ?

Comment: What is the type of `m_axisX`?

Comment: "how a reprex could be different than my program" - there is no information on the types involved in the code you posted. Only from the error i was able to know that it is a  `QVector`. PLease read about [mcve]. The code you posted can be correct or not depending on the code you didnt post

Comment: On every call the graph "scrolls" to the left, so the leftmost point is not shown. That's the point I wanna remove. So of course on the next call this number increases because my xValue increases.

Comment: @G.M. QValueAxis

Comment: `m_series` is holds all data points? If you move to the left, I'd expect that you remove always the first element. Why is the index of the element to be removed determined by the axis current min ?

Comment: i mean what I dont understand is that, if I call this function lots of times, then in each call you add one element to `m_series` and remove one element from it, ie number of elements stays same, but the index you want to earase increases unbounded, so it is just natural that at some point it will go out of bounds. What am i missing? Is there some code that adds more elements to the vector? Is the axis `min` decreased somewhere?

Comment: my guess is that in the case of "m_axisX range of (0, 20) the program crashes when trying to delete point 22." you start out with a vector of 21 elements, then instead of removing the "oldest" element at index 0, you remove element at index `m_axis.min()` and because the `min` increases in steps of `1` but the vector has only ever 21 elements you cannot erase element at index 22. Its just a guess, but I think you just need `m_series->remove(0);`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Oh ok, now I understand, this could be the problem. So when later in the program the minimum of m_axisX is 43, the index of this first point is still 0 whereas I thought it would be 43, right? (Which would not make any sense...) So I should always delete index 0, right?

Comment: Oh ok you've find the solution before me. I didn't see your comment while writing my own ;)

Comment: I wrote an answer, but note that in fact I cannot tell you if my answer is correct. Only you can know if you want to erase element at index 0 or the element at index `m_axisX->min()`, the code is too incomplete for me to understand it, though if you also cannot explain why it should be the element at index `min` then my guessing is probably right ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the index of the data points in the vector `m_series` and their `x` value. When the data point with `x = old_x_min` goes out of the window you want to display, then that data point is at index `0` not at index `old_x_min`.

Replace

```
m_series->remove(m_axisX->min());
```

with

```
m_series->remove(0);
```

to remove the oldest data point, instead of some data point in the middle of the series.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to say that removing the points makes a really big performance difference. When running to x=3000 it's over a minute!